# how to duplicate a string with malloc

Tags: c

I have this exercise where I need to duplicate a string using a malloc, I'm not sure where my error is (I have a segmentation fault).

```
/* Like the strdup() function. It creates a copy of the string on the heap.
* @note The copy is allocated using malloc().
* @to of warning the user is responsible for freeing the memory allocated for the new string
* @param str the string to duplicate
*/    
char * IMPLEMENT(duplicateString)(const char * str) {
    if(str==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    char *str2;
    str2=malloc(sizeof(*str));

    while(str!='\0'){
        *str2=*str;
        str=str+1;
        str2=str2+1;
    }

    *str2='\0';

    return str2;
}
```

Comment: What is `IMPLEMENT(duplicateString)` suppose to do?

Comment: Please indent your code

Comment: Next time, compile with all warnings and debug info i.e. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and **use the debugger `gdb`**

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don’t know how to implement this. Do you know anywhere I can learn?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to implement. Both `gcc` and `gdb` are free software tools (available on many OSes), that are usable on the command line. (I don't know what OS you are using; I strongly recommend installing then using some Linux distribution, because it is very developer- and student- friendly)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am using Ubuntu with CodeBlocks. I just installed gcc which I didn’t have, and I apparently already had gdb. I’m looking into how it works right now!

Comment: Avoid compiling thru CodeBlocks  (it will confuse you). Type a compilation command in some terminal.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch alright, can you explain why? And isn’t it more time consuming to do it this way? Is there a better software than code-blocks you would recommend?

Comment: Because you first need to be able to use `gcc` on the command line by yourself. Once you are familiar with that, you could configure your editor to run `gcc` for you (the way you want it to happen). If your editor is hiding important things (like the compilation step) to you, you don't understand what is going on. What you understand that, choose a good editor (my preference is `emacs` but YMMV) and configure it to fit your needs. Many newbies believe that they compile with their IDE (which is only an editor)

Comment: So the documentation to read about your compiler is the [one](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) for `gcc`, not for CodeBlocks. Likewise, the documentation to read about your debugger is for [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). I've seen many questions on SO from people who can't tell how their compiler was invoked and what version is it. Of course once you have read and understood how to [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) you can configure your IDE to do that faster.

Comment: But you need to learn to walk before you run. BTW, you surely want to also use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool and some version control tool. Again you don't want your IDE to hide that at first. Once you are familiar with the basic tools, do configure your IDE to run them with a single keypress.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch damn. Thank you so much for all those infos and recommandations. I’m in an engineer school, specialize in IT and they’re not telling us this at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `malloc` the number of characters hold by the `string`. So malloc would be

```
str2 = malloc(sizeof *str2 *(strlen(str)+1));
```

Also check the return value of `malloc`.

```
str2=malloc(sizeof *str2 *(strlen(str)+1));
if (!str2){
   // memory allocation failed.
}
```

Also you are doing some wrong thing in the loop

```
while(*str!='\0'){ // not `str` rather the `*str` you want to check.
    *str2 = *str;
     str  =  str +1;
     str2 =  str2+1;
}
```

In short you can do it

```
while(*str){
    *str2++ = *str++;
}
```

Also you are returning the `str2` which points to the `\0`. You need to store the beginning of the allocated memory some place so that you can return it.

```
str2 = malloc ..
if( !str2 ){
   // error
}
char *ret = str2; // storing it so that you can return it later.
..
..
return ret;
```

It's bad practice to use all capital name as function name. You can name it like `my_strdup()` or something meaningful.

Comment: Perhaps `while (*str)` and `str++;` amd `str2++;`

Comment: @EdHeal.: Edited..yes it will be more cleaner

Comment: Thnak you so much for your help and quick answer, I updated my code while you updated your answer, it works perfectly. I'm learning to use malloc, pointers... it's not simple!

Comment: @createurx make it simpler.  If you had, for instance, used 'int stringLength= sizeof(*str);', 'str2=malloc(stringLength);' and printffed out stringLength, (or stepped through and inspected it s value), you would have seen immediately that you were only mallocating one byte.

Answer (score 2):

This part is wrong `sizeof(*str)`. You need to find the length of the string, not the memory size of the first character (which is what this is doing)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the length of the string for the `malloc`.

Use the line

```
str2=malloc(strlen(str) + 1); // +1 for the null character to terminate the string
```